# Cancel a method by user input or non response

Tags: c#, asp.net

The website I am working on allows users to generate reports  between two dates that are selected by the user. The problem I am having is that if a user accidently requests a report between a massive date difference i.e. one year the server is put under a lot of pressure  and sometimes can crash for all users. What I what to do is have some kind of a progress bar showing the user how long the report is going to take and a cancel button or a button to check if they are still there. I was looking at using a cancel token with a task but am not sure is this is what I want. was also thinking about a global linked list with  random numbers linked to true false, as the user can open many reports at the same time. I have included some of the relevant code below . I would appreciate any help or a point in the right direction, Thanks

//java script which is passed from and too date and calls method genonereport

```
window.open('genonereport?idd=' + idd + '&fromm=' + 
fromm + '&too=' + too + '&filetype=' + outputValue ,
 '_blank');
```

// genonereport passes on the values to the class below which contains the relevant method 
---report.render which is the method that I want to cancel if user cancels report or if they leave

```
     public byte[] genReportBytes(int id, string fromm, string too, string filetype)
    {

        reportDetails repD = new reportDetails();
        repD = getOneReport(id);

        LocalReport report = new LocalReport();

        if (fromm != null)
            repD.ParametersCommandLine = "@startdate=" + fromm;

        if (too != null)
            repD.ParametersCommandLine += " @enddate=" + too;

        string RDLCPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RDLCPath"];
        string ReportOutputPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportOutputPath"];

        string RDLCName = repD.RDLCName;
        RDLCPath += @"\" + RDLCName;
        report.ReportPath = RDLCPath;

        string sqlGet = repD.SQLOfReport;

        report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(repD.DatasetName, getReportData(sqlGet, repD.ParametersCommandLine)));

        // export to byte array

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string filenameExtension;
        string deviceInf = "";
        byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
        byte[] empty = null; 
        string extension;
        bool Completed;

        if (filetype == "pdf")
        {
            deviceInf = "<DeviceInfo><PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight><PageWidth>11in</PageWidth><MarginLeft>0in</MarginLeft><MarginRight>0in</MarginRight></DeviceInfo>";
            //fileName = ReportOutputPath + @"\" + repD.NameOfOutputPDF + ".PDF";
            //Completed = ExecuteWithTimeLimit(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000), () =>
            //{
                bytes = report.Render("pdf", deviceInf, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
                                        out streamids, out warnings);
            //});

        }
        else
        {
            //fileName = ReportOutputPath + @"\" + repD.NameOfOutputPDF + ".XLS";
            //Completed = ExecuteWithTimeLimit(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000), () =>
            //{
            bytes = report.Render(
                  "Excel");
            //});
        }
        //if (Completed == true)
        //{
            return bytes;
        //}
        //else
            //return empty;
    }
```

// I have gotten this far but this only cancels after a certain amount of time which isn't much good to me

```
public static bool ExecuteWithTimeLimit(TimeSpan timeSpan, Action codeBlock)
    {
        try
        {
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => codeBlock());
            task.Wait(timeSpan);
            return task.IsCompleted;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            throw ae.InnerExceptions[0];
        }
    }
```

sorry about the long winded question, Thanks again

Comment: As a first step, why don't you restrict the timespan the user can select to say 6 months?

Comment: Unfortunately sometimes users will genuinely need reports spanning over a year as some of the reports are summary reports that only summarize the data for each day and don't take long to render. But then if a user runs a daily report for a year which contain ten minute intervals of values on each given day and a graph problems start to arise

Comment: So if you had some way to discern which type of report they want to run, summary or not, you could limit the date.. e.g. with crystal reports you only enter parameters once a report is selected... perhaps you could do similar... select a summary... let user specify dates... select a daily... let user specify dates with limitations.

Comment: "how long the report is going to take" how could you possibly estimate this? when taking into account network contention, db availability, cpu workload etc etc

Comment: Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323191/cancel-task-by-time

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need at least three web endpoints:

1. one to generate the report and return the results
2. one that your Javascript can request periodically to check on progress
3. one that your browser can request to cancel the task

You would need to store a handle to each task in a dictionary with some sort of id, so you can pass the id into queries 2 and 3.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492789/Starting-and-Monitoring-a-Long-Running-Task-Using) gives you an example of how to do this.

It's not simple, so limiting the size of the report that users can generate might be the preferred option.