# Cancel Queued Tasks by Time (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, task

I have a recursive program that calls itself to be run as a new task.

Complete Example Code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class Class0
    {
        const int initialTasks = 1;

        static void Main()
        {
            Class1 myClass1 = new Class1();
            myClass1.Go(initialTasks);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        const int childrenTasks = 100;
        const int fibonacciTarget = 1234567;

        double taskCount = 0;

        public void Go(int tasks)
        {
            for (int index = tasks; index > 0; index--)
            {
                double taskID = GetID();
                Console.WriteLine("Enqueue: {0}", taskID);
                Task mainTask = new Task(() => MainTask(taskID));
                mainTask.Start();
            }
        }

        private void MainTask(double taskID)
        {
            FibonacciToTarget(fibonacciTarget);
            Go(childrenTasks);
            Console.WriteLine("DONE   : {0}", taskID);
        }

        //cpu bound task
        private static void FibonacciToTarget(int target)
        {
            int a = 1;
            int b = 1;
            int x;

            loop:

            if (b > target) { return; }
            x = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = x;

            goto loop;
        }

        private double GetID()
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                taskCount++;
                return taskCount;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This runs fine for a while, but eventually it spawns too many tasks.

Is there a way to make queued tasks die if it takes longer than 1 minute to finish/start?

I have read this: [Cancel task by time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323191/cancel-task-by-time)
It seems to rely on the task already running, however my program is cpu bound so tasks may not even begin to run a minute after being enqueued.

Comment: Just a FYI, you should almost never call `new Task(` unless you are writing a task scheduler, you should use `Task.Run(` or create a `TaskFactory` if you need special options set.

Comment: _"Is there a way..."_ -- sure, there's always a way. What have you tried? Do you have a _specific_ question? Your code seems contrived, and has the obvious design flaw that each task creates 100 new tasks in an unbounded manner. Rather than killing off old tasks, it seems to me it would make more sense to not start so many tasks in the first place. But, because we don't know what you're _really_ doing, it's impossible to offer any actual, specific advice. Please improve the question.

Comment: It's terribly impressive to see code that actually uses a `goto`. Perhaps try `while (b <= target) { ... }`?

Comment: And why is `taskCount` a `double`? Why not an `int`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho it's a method for calculating cost of travel through a virtual road network. Each time a calculation occurs across the network it increases the cost of that route, ordering the route costs. The calculations are cpu bound and because the actual road network changes over time, enqueued calculations are wasted after a time window. The current method is to begin reporting for a minute, then ending the program (on repeat).

Comment: @UpTide - The issue with this code is that it is exponentially creating new tasks. So the timeout required to prevent too many tasks also needs to get exponentially smaller - but you're not doing that. Don't try to kill existing tasks - you need to simply limit the number of tasks created.

Comment: You should never get yourself into a situation where you have so many tasks running in parallel that new ones can't even start in a timely manner. You need to be able to manage the backpressure. Fire-and-forget tasks are not really acceptable here - you need to be able to keep track of each `Task` instance, ideally *observe* its result, and figure out whether you have enough capacity to start new ones.

Comment: @Enigmativity double, not int lets the program run longer without implementing a check for overflow. 2147483647 vs 9007199254740992 (bad I know.) goto instead of while, i have no defense.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy any reading on your solution that you would recommend?

Comment: @UpTide - In your real application what's the trigger for performing a new calculation? It would actually be useful for you to post the real code. What you've asked for is a prime example of an X-Y problem.

Comment: @UpTide - try using `ulong` then you can go to `18446744073709551615`.

Comment: @Enigmativity when a route through the network is used it triggers new calculations at every point that two or more routes cross, one new task for every route that's connected. Even backwards towards the source of the trigger.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy I was afraid of the hundreds of tasks which share that value.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy - No, he's recursively calling the `Go` method from within the tasks. `taskCount` is being updated by all the subtasks.

Comment: @UpTide - We can't help you without you posting your real code. The current contrived example is not the same as your real code.

Comment: @UpTide, my go-to reference for questions like this has always been Microsoft's [Patterns of Parallel Programming](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=19222), which introduces `Parallel.For` - the tool of choice for CPU-bound parallel work. If you insist on rolling a more complex solution, take a look at TPL Dataflow or, really, any other tool that supports limited degree of parallelism.

Comment: @Enigmativity, you are right of course - I should have noticed the nested `Go` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is making a task spawn 100 other tasks after consuming CPU time for a short while. That runs into positive feedback (action 1 leads to action 2 which leads back to action 1). You're going to render your computer unusable if you don't shut down the program before it starts eating your swap memory.

> Is there a way to make queued tasks die if it takes longer than 1 minute to finish/start?

Easiest way is to use `CancellationTokenSource` class mentioned in one of the answers in the question you've read. But if I understand you right, that would just make the program kill itself after one minute.

> it's a method for calculating cost of travel through a virtual road network. Each time a calculation occurs across the network it increases the cost of that route, ordering the route costs.

What you're wanting to implement is an algorithm for computing the solution for the travelling salesman problem. Doing it recursively is not a good idea at all as solving complexity is sky high `(n-1)!`

Use dynamic programming (and array access parallelizing with worker thread if you really want to get multithreaded) to solve this problem. Search around for the best algorithm for solving it. And if you really want a way to end the program quickly, have a `CancellationTokenSource` class shared will all the worker threads, and before every cycle of calculation they do check the `IsCancellationRequested` property.